# Which LINQPad am I running?

Tags: linqpad

According to the LINQPad website, there are several different builds

- The vanilla build ('download now' on the [homepage](http://www.linqpad.net/))
- X64 build
- AnyCPU build http://www.linqpad.net/Beta.aspx

How can I tell which I am running? The Help / About screen has a version number, but doesn't talk about platform.

Comment: The beta seems to be at 4.50.01 while my own version (vanilla) is at 4.48.01, so at least you can already rule that one out.

Comment: What does the expression IntPtr.Size return? If it is 4, then you are  either running the vanilla build or the AnyCPU version on a 32-bit operating system. If it returns 8, then you are using the AnyCPU build (and you must be on a 64-bit operating system) Also the X64 build on the homepage is just the non-beta version of the AnyCPU build.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The X64 build and the AnyCPU build are one and the same thing. I'll update the web site to make that clearer.

The **Help | About** screen will display (AnyCPU) after the version number if you're running that version.

Comment: Answer doesn't seem to apply to LINQPad 5. I don't see anything after the version number.

Comment: Actually it does. If your version number does not include AnyCPU, you have the vanilla build. You can download the LINQPad 5 Any CPU Build here: http://www.linqpad.net/GetFile.aspx?LINQPad5Setup-AnyCPU.exe

Comment: Is there any way to test in a script?

Comment: IntPtr.Size. This will return 8 with the AnyCPU build (assuming your OS is 64-bit).

Answer (score 3):

This may be an option as well.

There's a VS utility call CorFlags that can force an AnyCPU assembly to explicitly be 32bit on a 64 bit host.

I have added to environment variables (computer properties/advanced settings) to my host for easy conversion:

```
%linq32% = corflags k:\Downloads\LINQPad.exe /32BIT+ /Force&&k:\Downloads\LINQPad.exe
%linq64% = corflags k:\Downloads\LINQPad.exe /32BIT- /Force&&k:\Downloads\LINQPad.exe
------line difference is here----------------------^
```

When you run this from the VS command prompt, the path to CorFlags has been added to the app's environment table (%path%).  If you don't want to run from the VS command prompt, you'll need to fully qualify the path to CorFlags...and will likely need other paths added to %path%

The **&&** in the above is a command separator for cmd.exe.  CorFlags.exe runs first, then LINQPad.exe runs next.

So, i just run the VS command prompt and type %linq32% when i need it to run as 32bit and %linq64% when i need 64bit.

Helpful for loading your own assemblies that might be cross-bitness.

(note, while this comment may not be directly related, the search term "linqpad 32bit" show this post as #3 in google so i put here for others)